# Seaborn subplots massive whitespace

Tags: visualization, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot three heatmaps in a vertical column using Seaborns subplot method.

```
import seaborn as sns
initalCorr = inputX.corr()
secondaryCorr = inputX_corr.corr()
finalCorr = inputX[selected_columns_pvalue].corr()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, figsize = (15,45))
fig.suptitle('Heatmaps of correlation between features selected for training',
fontsize = 20)

sns.heatmap(data = initalCorr, center = 0, square = True, ax = axs[0])
axs[0].set_title('Correlation between all features', fontsize = 20)   

sns.heatmap(secondaryCorr, center = 0, square = True, annot = True, linewidths = .5, fmt = '.2f', ax = axs[1])
axs[1].set_title('Correlation between features slected for P-Value analysis', fontsize = 20)

sns.heatmap(finalCorr, center = 0, square = True, annot = True, linewidths = .5, fmt = '.2f', ax = axs[2])
axs[2].set_title('Correlation between finally selected features', fontsize = 20)
```

The graphs themselves plot fine but the title appears out of place relative to the plots.

[image: Image showing the out of place title text]

How do I make the title directly above the heatmaps?

Additional:
seaborn version 0.9.0
matplotlib version 3.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the title closer to the first figure. Just add the following two lines at the end of the code

```
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.95)
```

[image: ReduceWhiteSpace]